# Understanding would

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs, will-would

> **He would do it**

What does sentence this mean??  Does this mean any of the following four ways

> 1) He will do it (if some conditions are met)

---

> 2) He will do it (if some conditions are met, but now those conditions are not met , Probably I won't do it anymore)

---

> 3)Part of reported speech in some article. For example He said "He will do it" or future in the past

---

> 4) past habit

Answer (score 1):

Your first explanation comes closest.

The definition online for this form of would is:

> 2. (expressing the conditional mood) indicating the consequence of an imagined event or situation.

So there's an element of the hypothetical involved. "He will do it" communicates too much certainty, whereas "he would" is dependent on something else having happened. Even if the person is communicating "he would" because "it's part of who he is", there would still need to be some kind of trigger or set of circumstances under which the person "would" carry out the specified behaviour. "He will", on the other hand, suggests that it's actually going to happen.

**Update**

> 2) He will do it (if some conditions are met, but now those conditions are not met , Probably I won't do it anymore)

This one would be incorrect, as there is no implication that he won't/wouldn't do it any more.

> 3) Part of reported speech in some article. For example He said "He will do it" or future in the past

This seems more to do with the context than a specific meaning of the phrase? (I'm struggling to make sense of it.)

> 4) past habit

This one is correct, though I feel it would usually be contextualised in some way, e.g.:

> He would go for a walk in the park every once in a while.

Comment: Alternatively, **He would do it** is appropriate when A suggests to B someone who might be prepared or capable of doing it. For example: Mary tells John that she needs a gutter repaired. John responds that **the gardener would do it**.

Comment: @RonaldSole. Then how would, the john’s response that “The gardener does it” differs from john’s response that “the gardener would do it” differ?. Please explain, i am very bad at english

Comment: @Chris Mack.  So doesn’t it denote my other options 2,3,4???  4)Past habit 3)Future in the past.  2) I read somewhere “If I were free, I would come to party” means he is not free and he will not come. so was that wrong? Does that just means, if  I am busy i will not come but if i am not busy i will come.                    ———-

Comment: @RamtejaGuthikonda: See my updated answer. Also, “If I were free, I would come to the party” - this means that if it weren't for the thing that were preventing him from being free, let's say it got cancelled or something, he would go to the party.

Comment: @Chris Mack thankyou so much for your help. My long time confusion on will vs would is almost cleared. But please clear my final doubt. If you clear my doubt, it will/would  be useful for my examinations. Here being useful depends on , you helping  having hapoened. So should i use would? (as second clause is dependent on the first clause?)

Comment: It depends on tense: 1) (Present) If you clear my doubt, it will be useful for my examinations. 2) (Past) If you were to clear my doubt, it would be useful for my examinations. Both are valid. This is the other definition of "would": "past of will, in various tenses."